# EOFError when open https

Tags: ruby, https, open-uri

I've been trying to use facebook graph api, though ruby raise EOFError when open api url (https://graph.facebook.com/.....)
I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.2.2.
The code is as follows:

```
require 'uri'
require 'https'

access_token = open("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=app_id&client_secret=app_secret&grant_type=client_credentials"){|f|
   f.read
}
```

Got following error:

```
end of file reached

/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:133:in `sysread'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:133:in `rbuf_fill'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:132:in `rbuf_fill'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2022:in `read_status_line'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2011:in `read_new'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1050:in `request'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:248:in `open_http'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:242:in `open_http'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
app/models/news_release.rb:75:in `post_to_facebook_wall'
```

I thoroughly googled and searched about this error and tried such as httpparty, mechanism, fb_graph, and koala.
However those raise same efoerror.
It seems that there is a bug with ruby-1.8.6 or open-uri, but I don't want to upgrade ruby.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ssl is failing because you didn't fill out the parameters. Try it like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

app_id = 'fill_me_out'
app_secret = 'fill_me_out_too'
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{app_id}&client_secret=#{app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials"
access_token = open(url).read
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) Actually, the problem was my plugin... I overwrote HTTP class in my plugin and that cause error.  Everything works well after comment out those lines.